# How to delete note in terminal velocity

Tags: command-line, note-taking

I just found a command line note taking tool: [terminal_velocity](http://seanh.github.io/terminal_velocity/).

But I don't find a way to quickly remove a note, is there anyone knows how to do that?

Comment: Does `terminal_velocity -h` give you anything useful?

Comment: no, nothing about removing a note

Answer (score 1):

In the details section of the [documentation](http://www.seanh.cc/terminal_velocity/) it states:

```
Details

Notes are kept as plain text files in a notes directory (~/Notes by default).
```

You can `cd` into `~/Notes` and remove the file you want to delete:

```
$: cd ~/Notes
$: rm your-note.txt
```